# Is it necessary to use double exclamation points (!!) in order to make sure that an object is not null?

Tags: javascript

I've recently started using double exclamation points `!!` before an object to make sure that it's not null and that it's not undefined and not an empty string, to make sure that I encompass all the different ways that a variable can be empty.

Is this necessary? It's hard to read, for instance:
`if(!!name)` vs `if(name)`

Any opinions on this? I want my code to be safe and not get into conditions where a null pointer exception and other things can occur, but I also want my code to be readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're doing is already done by JavaScript natively.

`if( value ) {
}`

will evaluate to true as long as `value` is not:

- null
- undefined
- NaN
- empty string ("")
- 0
- false

[Check out the toboolean conversions in the specification.](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Comment: Does javascript also do this for ternary operators? For instance if I have `var hasName = name ? true : false;`

Comment: hasName = name is assignment, not a boolean test
but otherwise yes, because a ternary simply determines which output to use based on the conditional, which is evaluated in the same way.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no need at all for the double-bang if you're using the variable as the condition in an `if`. Simply `if (name)` is sufficient to ensure that `name` is not a *falsy* value. All object references are truthy; `null` is falsy.

Answer (score 4):

This is completely unnecessary unless you need a strict comparison to boolean `true`, for example:

```
switch (true) {
  case foo:
```

Should be

```
switch (true) {
  case !!foo:
```

Or alternatively, the verbose but more readable `Boolean(foo)` (don't use `new` with the primitive constructors). Note that opposite is not true, if you are testing for falsey values then it becomes a problem because 0, `NaN` and the empty string, which may be valid values, are falsey:

```
if (!foo) { // foo had better not be empty string or zero
```

However, JavaScript offers you an out here (that some frown on) involving *loose* equality, `null` and `undefined` are loosely equivalent to each other but not to any other falsey values:

```
null == undefined //true
null == NaN // false
undefined == '' // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Totally and completely ... pointless, to use a small pun.

The `if()` autmotically converts the conditional value to a boolean.

The `!!` converts it a boolean as well.

Where `!!` is sometimes used is to force something to a `boolean` value..

Such as:

```
var hasElement == !!document.getElementById("zz");
```